# C++ while loop is not reading -1 from my file

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I am writing a program that reads numbers from a .txt file and outputs a respective amount of asterisks (for even integers) and dollar signs (for odd integers). For example, a 3 would output $$$ and 2 would output **. The program works fine, except for when it reads the number -1. Other negative numbers work just fine, except for -1 for some reason..

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int value, even, odd;
ifstream infile;
infile.open("lab6_input.txt");

while (infile >> value)
{
    if (value % 2 == 0)
        cout << string(abs(value), "*$"[value % 2]) << endl;
    else
        cout << string(abs(value), "*$"[value % 2]) << endl;
    value++;
}
infile.close();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Here is my output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmDkS.jpg

The last number in the output is a -1, but it just displays an empty space.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a bit odd. Your variables are not initialized, even and odd are not even used. Your if statement is unnecessary because you have in both cases the same code.

To your question:
You should use `abs(value)` twice.
Try

```
while(infile >> value){
cout << string(abs(value), "*$"[abs(value) % 2]) << endl;
value++;
}
```

[Live example](https://onlinegdb.com/SJdRe6K_H)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here

```
"*$"[value % 2]
```

In C++, the result of the modulo operator applied to a negative number is negative (well, technically is [a bit more complicated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Remainder) than that). So, when `value` is negative, that instruction causes undefined behavior, accessing the array (string literal) out of bounds (the one at index **-1**).

You could solve the issue taking the absolute value of `value` or of the result, but consider writing a free function like the following, instead.

```
constexpr bool is_odd(int x)
{
    return x % 2;
}
```

It will better express the intent and will help the compiler to optimize your code (see e.g. [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Bwypsb)), because it's like you are asking

> Tell me if `value` *is* divisible by two (the remainder of its division by 2 is zero) or *not*.

Which is different from

> Give me the remainder of the division of `value` by 2

---

You may have noted, in linked Compiler Explorer page, that the compilers end up using a simple

```
and     edi, 1
```

Instead of performing an actual modulo operation. This is because what you really need is the less significant bit and you could directly use in your code

```
value & 1
```

Note, though, that the Standard (C++17, while I'm writing) doesn't mandates (yet, C++20 will require two's complement) a particular binary representation for type `int`, so the previous would be implementation defined (and wrong, if you happen to find a [ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement)  still working `int` implementation).